# Picasa API – Requesting thumbnails of a certain size

Tags: picasa

I am using the C# code shown below to retrieve thumbnails from an album using the Picasa API.  Can someone tell me how I can retrieve larger thumbnails by making changes to the code?

```
public void getimages (string albumid)
{
    PicasaService service = new Google.GData.Photos.PicasaService("test");
    PhotoQuery query = new PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(userName, albumid));
    PicasaFeed feed = service.Query(query);

    foreach (PicasaEntry entry in feed.Entries)
    {

        string title = entry.Title.Text.Substring(0, entry.Title.Text.LastIndexOf("."));
        Albumimages.Add(new AlbumImages(title, entry.Media.Thumbnails[0].Url, entry.Media.Content.Url));    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about C#, but the feed url have a parameter named 'thumbsize' :

URL example : https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/?kind=album&thumbsize=320

You can check the valid values here: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/reference#Parameters